# error en datagridview al dar click

Tags: c#, windows-forms, datagridview

tengo un datagridview en el cual muestro un listado de facturas, entonces cuando intento dar click a la primera factura me muestra este error," 
Esta operación no se puede realizar cuando se está cambiando de tamaño una columna de relleno automático." pero solo es con la primera linea del datagrid, ya quite en la propiedades el AutoSizeColumnsMode como None
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aqui otra imagen de cuando la selecciono, en todos las demas filas funciona sin ningun problema, como decia solo es en esta. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por cierto esta dentro de un bloque try

```
  if (dgvFactura.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Historico"].Selected)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        HistoricoPago hp = new HistoricoPago();
                        hp.idh = Convert.ToInt32(dgvFactura.CurrentRow.Cells["ID"].Value.ToString());
                        hp.paciente = dgvFactura.CurrentRow.Cells["NombreCliente"].Value.ToString();

                            hp.Show();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que definir la columna del tipo `DataGridViewButtonColumn`

[Crear una columna de botones con imagen usando la clase DataGridViewButtonColumn](https://geeks.ms/lmblanco/2009/09/16/crear-una-columna-de-botones-con-imagen-usando-la-clase-datagridviewbuttoncolumn/)

Para definir el icono usas el evento CellPaint

```
private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex >= 0 
        && this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "colBotones" 
        && e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All);

        DataGridViewButtonCell celBoton = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["colBotones"] as DataGridViewButtonCell;
        Icon icoAtomico = new Icon(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"Atomico.ico");
        e.Graphics.DrawIcon(icoAtomico, e.CellBounds.Left + 3, e.CellBounds.Top + 3);

        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

veras como se usa el `e.Graphics.DrawIcon` para asignar el icono

Ahora bien para detectar que boton se presiono se usa el `CellClick` nuevamente detectando que se presione sobre la columna del boton que interesa detectar

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{

    if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "colBotones")
    {
        var valCol = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["NombreColumna"].Value;

        //resto codigo

    }

}
```

Si tienes mas de una columna de botones deberas definir varios `if` uno por cada columna